# Iterate Pandas dataframe like a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a unique index for each row, so my dataframe looks like this -

```
>>>df.head()
    Alignment   Sequence    Sequence2b  Post2b  SequenceLength  Sequence2bLength    Name    Year    Clade   Country Patient medoid
index                                               
44644   MRV-KET----QMNWP---N----------L---W---K-------...   MRVKETQMNWPNLWKWGTLIFGLVIICSAADNLWVTVYYGVPVWRD...       AGY 778 0   AA111a_WG3  2009    01_AE   TH  AA111   NA
3616    ------T----QMNWQ---H----------L---W---K-------...   TQMNWQHLWKWGTLILGLVIICSASNLWVTVYYGVPVWKDADTTLF...   AVVKINENATLDDTSY    LKN 822 16  041_WK32    -   B   CH  041 NA
36025   MRV-KET----QMSWP---N----------L---W---K-------...   MRVKETQMSWPNLWKWGTLILGLVIMCSASDNLWVTVYYGVPVWRD...   D   NTS 843 1   AE_Env_CR11_Jan09D  2009    01_AE   TH  CR11    NA
42027   MRV-KGI----RKNCQ---H----------L---W---R-------...   MRVKGIRKNCQHLWRWGIMLLGMLMICSTAEKLWVTVYYGVPVWRE...   DADEIHNDDNSS    SCY 862 12  CR0058S 2002    B   US  -   NA
31626   MRV-RGI----PRNYP---Q----------W---W---I-------...   MRVRGIPRNYPQWWIWGILGFWMIIICRVMESSWVTVYYGVPVWTD...   DAIPLNGNSSNSSSNSSEY LIN 852 19  03ZASK006B2 2003    C   ZA  SK006   NA
```

Is there a way to iterate it easily sort of like a key,value pair like a dictionary like this?

```
for index in df:
   print index, df[index]['Name']
   break
 >>>44644 : {Name:AA11a_WG3}
```

Here is what I have come up with, but I'm not sure if this is the most "pythonic" way.

```
 for index in df.index:
     print index, df[df.index == index].Name
```

The df.to_dict does not work since it removes the index.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)?  Your example is a bit strange since you say you want to iterate over the DataFrame, but you are actually only using one column of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to use `iterrows()`.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
     print((idx, row.Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you (like me) want to iterate over rows and access each row as a dictionary, do this:

```
for item in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
     print(item)
```

using this you can access each cell by column_name.